# Add variable to json string or swap on click?

Tags: jquery, query-string, jsonp

Ok I using something like this

```
$.getJSON("http://myurl.com/search-ext.json&type=aaaaaa&callback=?",
```

working fine but now I need to add another type variable like this:

```
$.getJSON("http://myurl.com/search-ext.json&type=aaaaaa&type=bbbbb&callback=?",
```

Yes, they have the same name.... so can I insert another type or is there a way to swap out the string with an onclick?

Answer (score 0):

Add `[]` to the key in your URL:

```
$.getJSON("http://myurl.com/search-ext.json&type[]=aaaaaa&type[]=bbbbbb&callback=?",
```

Also, I don't know if you did this on purpose or not, but it at least appears as if you need a ? after .json:

```
$.getJSON("http://myurl.com/search-ext.json?type[]=aaaaaa&type[]=bbbbbb&callback=?",
```

Then, for instance in PHP, you will have an array on the server:

```
$_GET['type'] ~ array('aaaaaa','bbbbbb')
```

**EDIT**

Following the additional comments, I believe this is what you're looking for:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object

```
var newerQuery = $.query.SET('type', 'bbbbb');
var newURL = "http://myurl.com/search-ext.json?" + newerQuery;
$.getJSON(newURL);
```

An example:

http://jfcoder.com/test/gettypes.php?type=aaaaaa&callback=MyCallback

**EDIT 2**

```
<a href="href://www.somewhere.com/?type=aaaaaa&amp;other=yes&amp;another=yes&amp;yeti=neverseen" 
   onClick="return replaceType(this,'bbbbbb')">Link</a>

function replaceType(el, value) {
    sub = el.href.substring(0,el.href.indexOf('?'));
    split = el.href.substring(el.href.indexOf('?')+1).split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        if (split[i].indexOf('type=') !== 0) continue;
        split[i] = encodeURI("type="+value);
    }
    el.href = sub + "?" + split.join('&');
    alert(el.href);
    return false;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Phjsv/1/

Comment: Probably just left it out.  What will adding the []=bbbbb do? I'm cnfused - I'm trying to display different results depending on a clicked link.

Comment: One needs to be with the second type and one without it.

Comment: No php, this has to be javascript or jquery only

Comment: It sounds like what you wanted was a way to pass multiple `type`'s to the server using a GET string (`&type=aaaaaa&type=bbbbb`).

Comment: OR... Are you trying to REPLACE the `type` in the GET string?

Comment: No, no need to replace -  I can always keep the first type - just need to add another one to the url

Comment: @mark - See my edit. I think you want the jQuery plugin Query Object: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object

Comment: Wait a sec - they have the sam name - how will that work and can I set that from a link?

Comment: @mark - Your comment didn't make it. Also, I forgot to remove all of my `alert()` code, so see the current iteration. :)

Comment: @mark - Don't you want to replace the `type` with a newer `type`? I'm sorry, but I'm not quite following what you're trying to do...

Comment: no I have one type then I have to add another to the url when I click a link. So then I have two types in url.  I'll need to remove it too I guess sorry,  I am very tired!

Comment: Jusrt need to be able to swap back and forth from type=aaa and type=aaa&type=bbb

Comment: @mark - What's the point of `type=aaa&type=bbb`? One will override the other (http://jfcoder.com/test/gettypes.php?type=aaa&type=bbb). Do you want to redirect the browser, or just send the `type` key with a new value?

Comment: That's what I'm thinking. bbb will cancel out aaa right? They sent it to me like that.

Comment: @mark - No offense, by I don't know who "they" are. From what I gather, you have a URL. This URL has a GET string key/attribute of `key=aaaaaa`. You want to include links on a page in which this URL loads that allow the user to reload content on the page (using `$.getJSON()`) while "searching" for a different `key=value` from original key. Is this right?

Comment: The people I am doing the site for. And no, I need the original key and I need to add/remove a key with the same name

Comment: @mark - I'm going to need more context to understand what you're after. Taking a URL-encoded string and replacing a key's value is one thing, but the other part about an onclick and so forth, I'm not getting enough information about the implementation. Can you post some a link to a mockup of what you're working on, or the HTML/JS you have that would be affected?

Comment: Sorry I lost this thread.  OK, I think it is goingot be an issue.  Can you explain replacing a key - is this possible by clicking on a link?

Comment: @mark - See my last edit. If that doesn't do it, I'm not sure I can help.

Comment: @mark - Note, I noticed a couple missing elements and a stray `console`. Use the current edit.